# Compile data from multiple sources into a SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, aggregation

I have data stored in a local network database (SQL Express, connected to our MRP system), Excel files on a local file server, and on Teamwork.com project management site. I would like to combine data from these various sources to a SharePoint Online List. The List will be viewed by Engineers and Management to review Project status.

Are there OOTB solutions that exist that do this already?

If not, what would be a high level approach to solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box feature that you can use for this requirement.

Since the environment is SPO your best option is to create a Provider Hosted Addin. In that app you can have connection to various objects (SQL, Excel, etc.) and combine the result in required format and display it on HTML.

This link will guide you on how to start creating a provider hosted addin - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-started-creating-provider-hosted-sharepoint-add-ins